# C++11 best practice to use rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I am new to C++11. In fact until recently, I programmed only using dynamic allocation, in a way similar to Java, e.g.

```
void some_function(A *a){
   a->changeInternalState();
}

A *a = new A();
some_function(a);
delete a;

// example 2
some_function( new A() ); // suppose there is **no** memory leak.
```

Now I want to reproduce similar code with C++11, but without pointers.

I need to be able to pass newly created class `class A` directly to function `useA()`. There seems to be a problem if I want to do so with *non-const* normal reference and It works if I do it with rvalue reference.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A{
public:
        void print(){
                ++p; // e.g. change internal state
                printf("%d\n", p);
        }

        int p;
};

// normal reference
void useA(A & x){
        x.print();
}

// rvalue reference
void useA(A && x){
        useA(x);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        useA( A{45} );   // <--- newly created class 

        A b{20};

        useA(b);

        return 0;
}
```

It compiles and executes correctly, but I am not sure, if this is the correct acceptable way to do the work?

Are there some best practices for this kind of operations?

Comment: Including C headers in C++ is deprecated. Use the corresponding C++ headers instead, e.g. `<cstdio>` instead of `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: I am coming from C, this why I still uses old includes... question is for coding standard, do people uses && in a way I did in my example?

Comment: Note that if `a` does not have an `explicit` constructor,  you can write `useA(45);`

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would not design the code so that a temporary object gets modified. Then you would write your print function as:

```
void useA(A const & x){
    x.print();
}
```

and declare `A::print` as `const`. This binds to both rvalues and lvalues.  You can use `mutable` for class member variables which might change value but without the object logically changing state.

Another plan is to keep just `A &`, but write:

```
{ A temp{45}; useA(temp); }
```

If you really do want to modify a temporary object, you can write the pair of lvalue and rvalue overloads as you have done in your question. I believe this is acceptable practice for that case.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing about C++11 move semantics is that most of the time, you get them "for free" without having to explicitly add any &&s or std::move()s in your code. Usually, you only need to use these things explicitly if you're writing code that does manual memory management, such as the implementation of a smart pointer or a container class, where you would have had to write a custom destructor and copy constructor anyway.

In your example, A is just an int. For ints, a move is no different from a copy, because there's no opportunity for optimization even if the int happens to be a disposable temporary. Just provide a single useA() function that takes an ordinary reference. It'll have the same behavior.

Comment: where is the move in the code?  
I thought useA( A{45} ) makes temporary and give reference to this temporary to the function?

Comment: That is the move. To vastly oversimplify it, when you pass a temporary by value, the function argument is move constructed, and when you pass a named value by value, the function argument is copy constructed. It happens to be irrelevant in this case since the argument is a class whose sole member is an int.

Comment: probably then, the REAL question is what is the difference betwen void useA(A a) and useA(A &&a) ? I can modify the question if needed.

Comment: then probably the real question Is: does `void useA(A &&a)`  commonly used in C++11 programs? I did not saw it in any examples so far.

Comment: It's definitely not *common*, because as I said it should almost never be used outside of a class that does manual memory management. Trying to use it anywhere else probably won't do anything but confuse the compiler, since it'll already use move semantics when possible. In the vast majority of modern C++11 code, all the error-prone memory management should be encapsulated by standard container classes and smart pointers, so that your code doesn't have to worry about any of it and you get these optimizations for free.

Comment: last question - the very first code (with pointer), how it must be translated to non pointers? especially this part `some_function( new A() );`

Comment: If you have a function like some_function(...) that takes a pointer you must be sure they do not take the ownership. If the function does only perform some operations you can generate the object on the stack and use the address operator: 

    A on_stack; 
    some_function(&on_stack);

Comment: @Ixrec no, there is no move in OP's code. There are only two objects `A{45}` and `b` and neither is moved, they are passed by reference